# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: react-native, node-modules

```
I am getting this error in my react native project, i found some solutions about 
this error but that was not working for me, solution i found for this error is like 
update your build gradle version and i change build gradle version, but still 
getting same error this is the exact error which i get in android studio.

can anyone help me to solve this problem.
```

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
  at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
  at
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCrop found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCrop$Options found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$1 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$2 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$3 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$4 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$5 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$6 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$7 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$8 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity$GestureTypes found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.callback.BitmapCropCallback found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.callback.BitmapLoadCallback found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.callback.CropBoundsChangeListener found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.callback.OverlayViewChangeListener found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.model.AspectRatio found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.model.AspectRatio$1 found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.model.CropParameters found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.model.ExifInfo found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.model.ImageState found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.task.BitmapCropTask found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.task.BitmapLoadTask found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.task.BitmapLoadTask$BitmapWorkerResult found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.BitmapLoadUtils found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.CubicEasing found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.EglUtils found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.FastBitmapDrawable found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.ImageHeaderParser found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.ImageHeaderParser$RandomAccessReader found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.ImageHeaderParser$Reader found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.ImageHeaderParser$StreamReader found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.RectUtils found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.RotationGestureDetector found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.RotationGestureDetector$OnRotationGestureListener found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.RotationGestureDetector$SimpleOnRotationGestureListener found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.util.SelectedStateListDrawable found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.view.CropImageView found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.view.CropImageView$WrapCropBoundsRunnable found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)
> Duplicate class com.yalantis.ucrop.view.CropImageView$ZoomImageToPosition found in modules jetified-pictureselector-v2.7.3-rc08-runtime (io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08) and jetified-ucrop-2.2.6-native-runtime (com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native)

```
 build.gradle: 

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        jcenter { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url 
        'https://artifactory.img.ly/artifactory/imgly' }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android- 
        tools/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        classpath 'ly.img.android.sdk:plugin:8.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
        classpath 'ly.img.android.pesdk:plugin:9.1.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
        plugin:1.4.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
        plugin:1.4.10"
        classpath 'ly.img.android.sdk:plugin:9.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react- 
            native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 
        'https://artifactory.img.ly/artifactory/imgly' }
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        jcenter { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

try the below provided solution.

Add this section in app level build.gradle file in android {} section

```
 configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'ucrop' // This removes all other versions of `ucrop` if gets duplicated from all the artifacts.
}
```

Comment: i have been working on a project using image_cropper on flutter and this solution finally works

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is coming some where in crop image class I am not able to identify the library but this what worked for me :

1. Add to android/gradle.properties:

> ```
> android.enableJetifier=true
> android.useAndroidX=true
> ```

1. `yarn add jetifier`
2. In android directory run: `./gradlew clean`
3. Run: `yarn jetify` in your project directory
4. `react-native run-android`

Another solution :

replace : `implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native'` to

```
 implementation 'io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v2.7.3-rc08'
```

then go to

> node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/PickerModule.java

add `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;` to imports and replace `uCrop.start(activity);` to `uCrop.start(activity, UCrop.REQUEST_CROP);`

Reference : https://githubmemory.com/index.php/repo/baronha/react-native-multiple-image-picker/issues/52

Comment: Hey @Iva thanks for your solution but i tried this and this is not working for me do you have any another solution.

Comment: can you share your build.gradle in question

Comment: of app folder build gradel or normal ?

Comment: project gradle file

Comment: gradel file is added you can check now.

Comment: I have posted one alternative try that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247499/discussion-between-iva-and-varun).

Answer (score -2):

Add this section in app level build.gradle file in android {} section

```
 configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'ucrop' // This removes all other versions of `ucrop` if gets duplicated from all the artifacts.
}
```